# Remote Signing (DocuSign) - Some recipients not receiving emails

Tags: docusignapi

### Issue:

I have a working production process for initiating remote signing via the DocuSign REST API.  For the most part, it works great.  However, for the initial 20 contracts we've sent out, a few clients have not received their emails from DocuSign requesting their signature.  I can confirm that DocuSign reports that they successfully SENT them to the signers even though clients have reported never receiving them (despite looking through spam/junk/deleted).  In these few circumstances we're stuck at a dead-end because if they don't receive that email for whatever reason, we have to revert back to manual contracts.

Having read through the following article:

https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/Why-aren-t-my-signers-receiving-DocuSign-Notification-emails

It's clear that this is a common issue and the only options we have is to either send it to another email address, have the client reach out to their ISP and figure out why it might be rejected (This is not a good / professional option), or resort to a manual contract.

#### One thought I had...

was to use the API to obtain the link for the current signer that DocuSign provides in the emails they send and give my app's users an alternative option to send our branded email containing this link to the remote signing page from our email service since we have zero reputation issues.

> ***Edit based on Inbar's reply***
>
> After reading through [Larry's Blog](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/long-lived-embedded-signing-urls) as provided by Inbar in the comments below, my idea above would need to have my app send an email to the signer with a unique URL back to my ***App*** (so that this URL is Long-Lived / limited only based on business rules) which, when clicked, would make a request to EnvelopeViews:createRecipient (time-limited / must be used in 5 mins) to retrieve a url and redirect the user to the Remote Signing page which is governed by DocuSign's session policy.
> Should my client need to go away and click the link in their email again, the Long Lived ==> Time Limited & redirect would repeat starting a new session.

Support seems to be better here on SO than via ticketing, so I'm hoping a DocuSign rep/guru has some ideas on what I can do to handle these scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, yes there are cases where emails from DocuSign are rejected as SPAM by the ISP or by the email provider. These will not even show in the spam folder because they reject them before they send them to the end-user and we do need to work with these to fix the issue. Especially if these users will be receiving more than one contract etc. For that - you will need to contact support since we need to know the email address etc.

Your idea is possible, but you'll have to read [Larry's blog](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/long-lived-embedded-signing-urls) here. This is because the URLs are typically very short lived and expire in 5 min so sending the regular URLs over email will not work very well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and the link to Larry's blog.  My google searches on the topic didn't land me there.  I added a revision to my question based on what I think Larry's blog is saying I can do.  Can you confirm that the single use / time-limited url returned with EnvelopeViews:createRecipient can be used to redirect the user to a remote signing session?

Comment: I think it's the other way around, you create your own URL that goes on your server, generates a URL using EnvelopeViews:createRecipient and then redirects the user to that URL.

Comment: I think we're saying the same thing, but I'm not being clear.  My app link emailed to client => client clicks my link ==> link goes to my app => app calls EnvelopeViews:createRecipient to get single use link => app redirects user to single use link (remote signing).

Comment: yup, perfect. Let me know if you need anything else.